# How to have my program look for a href with both keywords AND color

Tags: python

I am trying to find an href from a website. To find it, I have my program look for hrefs that include keywords and a certain color (I'm trying to get clothing) This is what I have so far:

```
for url in soup.find_all('a'):
        if keywords in url.get_text():
            continue
        if color in url.get_text():
            links = (url['href'])
```

My program is picking up items that may have incorrect keywords and correct colors, or vice-versa. Never both. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Combine your check, `continue` will continue going through the loop and begin again at the next member of the iterator, not follow your logic further (which is the default logic)

```py
    ...
    text = url.get_text()
    if keywords in text and color in text:
        links = (url['href'])
```

Example `continue` use (note 3 is missing because the loop is continued)

```py
>>> for x in range(5):
...   if x == 3: continue
...   print(x)
...
0
1
2
4
```

Alternatively you could use `continue` for the case

```py
if keywords not in url.get_text():
    continue
```

if `keywords` is also an iterable (rather than a single value as your code implies), you should iterate over it too (with another `for` loop) your logic may be clearer shuffling this off to another function, using some check value, or using the `else` of a loop to `break` out of it

```py
urls = []  # start an empty list to collect the URLs in

for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    text = url.get_text()
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in text:
            print("found {} in text".format(keyword))  # optional
            break  # escape iterating over keywords
    else:  # did not find and break
        print("failed to find any keyword in text")
        continue  # next url in soup.findall

    for color in colors:
        if color in text:
            print("found {} in text".format(color))  # optional
            urls.append(url['href'])
            break  # one color is sufficient, escape color loop
    # loop will continue at next url
```